# Facebook iPhone SDK Checkin To Foursquare Place

Tags: iphone, facebook, foursquare, checkin

Admittedly I've not done a lot of experimenting but I thought someone might be able to give me a quick answer and save all that experimenting.

I have an app which uses Foursquare's API to find locations for the user.  I want the person to be able to check in to these places on Foursquare (easy) but also I want to check them in to the same place on Facebook regardless of if it exists or not (and it seems I need a PlaceID to check the user in?).  Is there an easy way to do this?  I've seen several apps doing it but are they doing some sort of behind the scenes search / hooking to get the Foursquare place linked to the Facebook place?

Thanks in advance!  If no one has a quick answer for me I'll post an answer to my own question when I eventually figure it out.

Comment: Can you please name those several apps doing it ? Interested to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create places dynamically on the Facebook Places API, I believe, but you would be able to easily share a user's foursquare checkin to Facebook using the *broadcast* parameter to checkins/add (See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add).

While this wouldn't create a "Facebook Check-in" in the old sense, it would still create an OpenGraph story and an entry on their Facebook "Places I've Been Map" since foursquare is now using OpenGraph to send a lot more data when you share (see http://blog.foursquare.com/2012/03/13/foursquare-on-facebook-is-now-prettier-check-out-the-new-look-for-foursquare-check-ins-badges-and-mayorships/).

This way you would still allow users to check in using the foursquare places database and share that check-in and whatever content you add to it out to both their foursquare and Facebook friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Public APIs to create places on the Graph API, hence the requirement for an existing Place ID.